# Element is not clickable at point. Chrome. Webdriver. Python

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium, xpath

it's already well known bug, usually it has three ways to avoid it: check overlapping, setup sleep time to completely page download, check visible of element.
I tried all of them, but they aren't working.
Well:
I'm working with twitter page
https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authenticate?oauth_token=3b8ougAAAAAABl35AAABWpZgqDA
The text filds have HTML:

```
<label for="username_or_email" tabindex="-1">Username or email</label>
<input aria-required="true" autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off" autofocus="autofocus" class="text" id="username_or_email" name="session[username_or_email]" type="text" value="">
```

I tried code:

```
def input_label:
    links = get_driver().find_elements_by_xpath("//label[@for='username_or_email']")
    if links:
        links[0].send_keys(str(UserName))
    else:
        raise ValueError('Field with label for username_or_email not found')
```

And i tied code:

```
def input_id:
   links = get_driver().find_elements_by_xpath("//input[@id='username_or_email']")
    if links:
        links[0].send_keys(str(UserName))
    else:
        raise ValueError('Field with id username_or_email not found')
```

I tried it with click on this elemrnt before send_keys, and without. But all my solutions didn't work. I always had an error message "Element is not clickable at point...".
Any advises?

Answer (score 0):

You're first try was sending text to a label. You're second try is on the right track. However, there is no `id` attribute to the `input` element. change `id` to `name`, then change `links[0].send_keys()` to `links[1].send_keys()`:

```
def input_id:
   links = get_driver().find_elements_by_xpath("//input[@name='username_or_email']")
    if links:
        links[1].send_keys(str(UserName))
    else:
        raise ValueError('Field with id username_or_email not found')
```

EDIT: to clarify, i see there is an `id` attribute in the HTML you posted, but it doesn't exist on the Twitter login element i was able to find.

EDIT 2: If the problem is related to the element not fully loading before your script tries to fill in credentials, try using `WebDriverWait`. an example would be something like:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

driver = webdriver.Chrome([path to your chromedriver])


# code that navigates to wherever you are going...


WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(expected_conditions.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//input[@name='username_or_email']")))
#                     ^ this is how many seconds you want to wait

links = get_driver().find_elements_by_xpath("//input[@id='username_or_email']")
if links:
    links[0].send_keys(str(UserName))
else:
    raise ValueError('Field with id username_or_email not found')
```

Comment: Thanks for your point. To clarify: I have no issues with my xpath, i checked it in console, and it will be the same element as if I used `name` attribute. And 100% I can't use  `links[1].send_keys(str(UserName))`
because my list has just one element and it has index 0 (it's list element numeration: first-0, second - 1 ... and so one).

Comment: gotcha. i modified and tested it against the twitter login page, which worked. i did this because the link you provided is inaccessible to us, so we don't have anything to go against.

Comment: Thanks. Which browser did you use? You can use any app which use twitter api (for ex.: buffer.com) to log in to reach page which I have. Page is inaccessible because token is expired.

Comment: i tested with Chrome using Chromedriver since you had google-chrome tagged. i didn't realize you're using this to use 3rd party twitter authentication. i'll run some tests and see if i can figure it out.

Comment: hmm, using buffer.com and the original code you provided in your 2nd try (`find_elements_by_xpath("//input[@id='username_or_email']")`), i had no problem executing the code. is there a chance the element hasn't fully loaded yet before the script tries to execute? if so, you can use the WebDriverWait functionality to see if that helps. i edited my post to include sample code for this.

Comment: I tried to use different sleep intervals. But it doesn't work. Honestly, I thought, that it is well known issue. Sometime webdriver for chrome can't catch element and send keys even by right xpath. As I understood it connected with position of element on the screen. And I know that my code is accurate. It will work, for ex.: in firefox, or if I change my screen resolution. Just to explain, i'm looking for any solution how i can send keys to element without any locators. For ex.: click and sent keys in current position. Somthing like it...

Comment: crookedleaf, which chrome version, and webdriver version did you use?

Comment: @AlexTestor i'm using Chrome 55.0.2883.87 and Chromedriver 2.27. furthermore, i'm using Selenium 3.0.2 with Python 2.7.12